# Android - AutoCompleteTextView: allow item user insertion if it is not in the list

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, onitemclicklistener

I have an AutoCompleteTextView object in my Android app. 
Just a question: if I select an item from the list, OnItemClickListener start. But if I don't select a list item but I insert the new one, which event should start?
Thanks!

Comment: see TextWatcher documentarion

Comment: But...does not exist a listener for 'onLastFocus' event? TextWatcher call for every character 'afterTextChanged', 'beforeTextChanged' and 'onTextChanged' methods.

Comment: ok, so maybe i didnt understand you correctly, so what actually do you want? you dont use the dropdown but...?

Comment: if user select an item from the list, OnItemClickListener start and I save an object with selected value. If user insert your own element (not present in list) I want set to null old object and save the new one...but I don't know which listener I must add for this.

Answer (score 0):

[SetOnHierarchyChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setOnHierarchyChangeListener%28android.view.ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener%29) should do the job for you. It indicates when new views are added and removed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an array or arraylist in AutoCompleteTextView then add the data from the user to aray